# difference between convolution2d and conv2d in tensorflow in terms of ussage

Tags: filter, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

In TensorFlow for 2D convolution we have:

```
tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter, strides, padding, use_cudnn_on_gpu=None,
             data_format=None, name=None)
```

and

```
tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d(*args, **kwargs)
```

- I am not sure about differences?
- I know that I should use the first one if I want to use a special filter, right? But what else? Especially about outputs?

Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`tf.nn.conv2d(...)` is the core, low-level convolution functionality provided by TensorFlow. `tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(...)` is part of a higher-level API build around core-TensorFlow.

Note, that in current TensorFlow versions, parts of layers are now in core, too, e.g. `tf.layers.conv2d`.

The difference is simply, that `tf.nn.conv2d` is an op, that does convolution, nothing else. `tf.layers.conv2d` does more, e.g. it also creates variables for the kernel and the biases amongst other things.

Check out the Tensorflow Tutorial on CNNs which uses Tensorflow core ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn)). With the low-level API the convolutional layers are created like this:

```
def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
```

Compare that to the TF Layers Tutorial for CNNs ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers)). With TF Layers convolutional layers are create like this:

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
  inputs=input_layer,
  filters=32,
  kernel_size=[5, 5],
  padding="same",
  activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

Without knowing your use case: Most likely you want to use `tf.layers.conv2d`.

Comment: Hi @sepidehsadatHoseyni, welcome to StackOverflow. This answer looks fine to me, and you seem satisfied too, so you should mark it as "accepted". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there will be no difference between `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` and `tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D` in Tensorflow 2.x.
[Here's the link for the illustration](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D)

In tensorflow 2.x, `keras` is an API in `tensorflow`